# Python requests module crashing when fed URL with emoji in it. Why?

Tags: redirect, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the following site:

https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%e2%99%a5%e2%80%8a-ny-logo-dead-at-91/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%e2%99%a5%e2%80%8a-ny-logo-dead-at-91/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(site).content, 'html.parser')
```

I get:

```
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded {} redirects.'.format(self.max_redirects), response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

I would like to understand what is going on. I suspect some loop generated somehow by the special characters being interpreted but I am at a loss rn.

Comment: Use `site = 'https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-♥-ny-logo-dead-at-91/'`

Comment: That will not work. I get the % encoding from beautifulsoup findall <a>. So yea.. im not feeding it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You asked why this happens. It is due to requests using urllib3. The urllib3 changes the percent-encoded bytes to upper case https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1677 as per the recommendation of RFC 3986 to uppercase percent-encoded bytes during normalization. In normal circumstances that would be good. But this server has seems to want it's URLs lowercase. This can be see by :

```
import requests
url = 'https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%e2%99%a5%e2%80%8a-ny-logo-dead-at-91/'
resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)

print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.headers['Location'])
print(resp.url)
```

Outputs:

```
301 
https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%e2%99%a5%e2%80%8a-ny-logo-dead-at-91/
https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%E2%99%A5%E2%80%8A-ny-logo-dead-at-91/
```

This shows it is a HTTP 301 redirect. The URL it is redirecting to and the URL the request was made to.

You can test this by opening Firefox or Chrome, right clicking on a page, Select Inspect, then select Network, select disable cache, then paste the last URL and hit return. You will see the 301 redirect.

I expect there is a directive on the server to make all URLs lowercase by forcing a redirect. So it goes into a loop of requesting with uppercase percent-encoded bytes and being redirected to a URL with lowercase percent-encoded bytes to which it makes a request with uppercase percent-encoded bytes etc.

There is a way round it but it could lead to unexpected side-effects and I would only use it as a last resort and then only if you were certain all your URLs were formatted as the server expects them. But it explains the problem.

```
import requests.packages.urllib3.util.url as _url
import requests


def my_encode_invalid_chars(component, allowed_chars):
    return component


_url._encode_invalid_chars = my_encode_invalid_chars
url = 'https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%e2%99%a5%e2%80%8a-ny-logo-dead-at-91/'
resp = requests.get(url)

print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.headers)
print(resp.url)
print(resp.text)
```

Note the output is:

```
200
{'Server': 'nginx', ... 
https://nypost.com/2020/06/27/milton-glaser-designer-of-i-%e2%99%a5%e2%80%8a-ny-logo-dead-at-91/
```

The response is HTTP 200 OK.
There is no Location header (I truncated the output).
The URL that was requested is lowercase.
Then it prints the page source.

Comment: Thanks so much! this helped a lot. I need to keep this in mind to avoid the script crashing or not working properly. Thanks again